# get all data from a variable

Tags: php, get

if i want to see what data is available into a variable, i fetch the data like ---
**get(0)** to get the **first data** like 'www.hello.com/23/23', **get(1)** to get the second data like 'www.mydomain.com/it/12', and so on ....

```
$apartmentId = $user->getApartment()->get(0)->getId();
```

Now if there are more data available in the **getApartment()**, which method i should use to get all the id's which is available in **getApartment()** !

i Have tried getAll() method which dose not working in this case. Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem. Thanks in advanced .

Comment: Maybe you can show us some code or we should imagine it?

Comment: Is this part of some API that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: yes, it is a part of some API, which i did not mention :)

Comment: then you'll have to look into the docs of that API which methods are provided. (Or have a look in the class itself)

Comment: What do you get returned if you don't pass an id in the get-method `get()`? An error or maybe an array?

Comment: an empty array i get if i pass a method of get()

Comment: then you'll have to have a look in the docs (or the source code) of that API, since guessing didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get all values, is to use a `foreach()` loop.

```
<?php

$var = array(
        'value_One',
        'value_Two',
        'value_Three',
        'value_Four',
        'value_Five'
        );

foreach($var AS $value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
}

?>
```